# How could I import data from Rally into a Sybase database?

Tags: rally

To include Rally data in our Cognos reports we need to import Portfolio items and UserStory information into a Sybase database. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use any ETL tool you have around (Cognos DataManager maybe an option) or
2. [bcp utility if you have source in csv](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility195.htm)
3. [or some code like this if your source is Excel](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/questions/515/how-do-i-fix-the-ability-to-edit-data-in-a-linked-excel-spreadsheet-has-been-disabled?page=1#518)